# Your connection is not private issue in browser after replacing the SSL certificate in server

Tags: ssl, server, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

Recently we have changed the server SSL certificate , once the server are restarted am trying to access my SSL enabled server from my Browser while trying same am getting the below error

Your connection is not private
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Please help me on this to fix the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the server? If you are using a self signed cert, make sure it's installed in the machine where you are using the browser.

Comment: In my keystore.jks file i have three entries of certificate One is root , intermediate and SSL certificate all there i need to add in Browser ? please suggest your thought

Comment: Your browser does not trust the new certificate authority. If it isn't well-known you will either have to use another one or ensure that its certificate is installed in all browsers. Guess which is easier ;-)

Comment: @Babu Ganesh, you can install the certificate in your machine by converting it into .pfx for windows